# Comparison method violates its general contract! Based on Map comparison

Tags: java, collections, compare

I'm trying to sort a `List<Map<string,Object>` based on date attribute inside a Map. Here is the code I used. But it throws an exception as follows.

Code:

```
Collections.sort(dataList,new Comparator<Map<String, Object>>() {

        public int compare(Map<String, Object> o1, Map<String, Object> o2) {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

            Date date1 = null;
            Date date2 = null;
            try {
                date1 = formatter.parse(o1.get("date").toString());
                date2 = formatter.parse(o2.get("date").toString());
            } catch (ParseException e) {

            }
            if(date1!=null && date2!=null){
                return date1.compareTo(date2);
            }else {
                return 0;
            }

        }
    });
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:868)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:485)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:410)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:214)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:217)
```

Can anyone help me to identify the problem with my code.? Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison isn't transitive.

- Object A: null.
- Object B: 1 Jan 2000.
- Object C: 1 Jan 2010.

A == B. A == C. B < C.